# Is the word 'Hobbyist' a weird language exception?

Tags: orthography, suffixes

So generally words with a *yist* sound at the end are represented with an *iest* suffix, for example *scariest* or *crappiest*.

However the word *hobbyist* is not.

Is there a defined reason for this? I can't find another example like it.

Comment: Well there's also lobbyist.  Both lobby and hobby are nouns, whereas scary and crappy are adjectives.

Comment: Well, -est is a superlative suffix and -ist denotes an agent (*detectorist, motorist...*). It's not a *sound* thing, it's a *meaning* thing.

Comment: @John Feltz - That was the answer I was after! If you want to copy it into and answer I'll mark it as such

Comment: Actually, @Andrew Leach has the full answer.  I just noticed the pattern.

Comment: The OP seems to be confusing adjectival superlatives that take IEST where the Y changes to iest (funniest, merriest) with nouns.

Comment: Ah John, that's what I meant, I confused the user name!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a misconception.

Comment: Feel free, it's been explained how it's an incorrect assumption. Thinking if I should just delete?

Comment: I am completely unaware of a close reason for a misconception. The closest is gen. ref. but am I unsure of what sort of gen. ref. resources exist to warrant closure for that reason. Results for [word end Y suffix](http://tinyurl.com/jzt2q9k) on a search engine don't seem to return relevant results. I'd recommend against deletion as this question may be helpful to other people with the same misconception. If anything, move it to E.L.L., since the answer relates to a somewhat basic rule I can find in Merriam-Webster's New International Dictionary 3rd Ed. but offline dictionaries aren't gen. ref.

Comment: And then there's accompanyist, which was preferred by Charles Dickens (Oliver Twist) and Henry W. Fowler but which is now regarded by some as  rather old fashioned.

Comment: [This](http://www.puzzlers.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=solving:wordlists:dictionary_search) is a good resource for searching the English dictionary for patterns (I probably learned about it on this site). If you search for `yist$` (“yist” at the end of a word), you find “copyist”, “entryist”, “essayist”, “partyist”, “queryist”, “rallyist”, “tolstoyist”, and the ones already mentioned here (“hobbyist”, “lobbyist” and “accompanyist”), and a few whose status as words is dubious (e.g., “poultryist”).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, your problem arises from the suffix used.

**Hobby, lobby**  +  **-ist**  ->  **Hobbyist, lobbyist**

**Crappy, scary** +  **-est** ->  **Crappiest, scariest**

If you tried to remove the 'y' from *hobby* you would end up losing the sound, clearly *hobbist* doesn't work.
Your other alternative is to change the 'y' go and 'i'; *hobbiist* is definitely not nice.
All this leaves you with a much nicer alternative of **hobbyist**

Answer (score 6):

The difference between words ending in *-ist* and *-est* is one of the **meaning** of the suffix.

- *-est* indicates a superlative (*scariest, crappiest* = most scary, etc.)
- *-ist* indicates an agent (*motorist, hobbyist* = one who drives a motorcar, etc.)

Which suffix is used has nothing to do with the sound at all.

Whether *-y* becomes *-i-* when a suffix is used depends on the suffix: it does happen with the comparatives *-er, -est* or with certain agent nouns like *multiplier;* but English will never change *-y* to *-i-* when what is added starts with an *i*. *Hobbyist* is not spelled *hobbiist.*

Comment: Note that although the generic superlative suffix has the vowel /ɛ/ and the agentive suffix -ist has /ɪ/, both of these result in the same pronunciation  after -y /ij/: /ijɛ/ (but this may be because of pen-pin merger in my own idiolect).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Would you mind if I edited in relevant citations to Webster's New International Dictionary 3rd ed's. rules? It'd mostly be just for citation's sake, although there is one rule that conflicts with a statement you've made: Single syllable comparatives and superlatives may optionally change -y to -i, as is the case with [shier](http://www.tfd.com/shier), (although [shyer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shyer%2Cshier&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshier%3B%2Cc0) is the preferred form in that case).

Comment: @Mitch: The pen-pin merger is only before nasals as far as I know; I think the relevant factor here is vowel reduction. (Do you really use /ɛ/? The vowel here is usually transcribed /ɪ/ or /ə/; as far as I can tell, accents without the weak vowel merger, such as "[RP](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/case-studies/received-pronunciation/vowel-sounds-rp/)," use /ɪ/ in both suffixes.)

Comment: @suməlic What's the vowel in 'best'? Isn't it usually  /ɛ/?

Comment: @Mitch: Yeah. "Best" is a monosyllable, so the vowel is stressed. Most people hear a difference between their pronunciation of the stressed vowel in "best" and "west" and their pronunciation of the unstressed vowel in "longest" and "hobbyist." Then again, in fully unstressed syllables like this with reduced vowels,  /ɛ/ and /ɪ/ don't contrast, so it's not so surprising that someone might identify the neutralized vowel as /ɛ/ rather than as /ɪ/.

Comment: I don't know what all these comments quoting IPA are about. Which suffix is used has nothing to do with the sound (whatever sound it is): it's purely to do with meaning. Superlatives use *-est* and agents use *-ist.*